# Сравнение трех словарей

Tags: python

есть три словаря

```
dict1={'key1':'5.00','key2':'84.00'}
dict2={'key3':'24.00','key4':'21.00'}
dict3={'key5':'100.00','key6':'50.00'}
```

как их правильно сравнить, чтобы получить **ключ наименьшего значения**?

вот так можно получить ключ наименьшего значения по одному словарю :

```
converted_to_num = dict((k, float(v)) for k,v in dict1.items()) # Конвертируем значения в число

print(min(converted_to_num, key=converted_to_num.get)) # получаем минимальное значение
```

как сравнить сразу все три словаря ?

т.е чтобы на выходе было : key1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно объединить словари и найти минимальное значение:

```py
dict1={'key1':'5.00','key2':'84.00'}
dict2={'key3':'24.00','key4':'21.00'}
dict3={'key5':'100.00','key6':'50.00'}


dict1.update(dict2)
dict1.update(dict3)
converted_to_num = dict((k, float(v)) for k,v in dict1.items())
print(min(converted_to_num, key=converted_to_num.get))
```

Comment: @Sevastopol' С Новым Годом Вас!!! Рад снова видеть. Моя почта - helpwithcredit1@gmail.com

Comment: @Sevastopol' Как же я рад Вас видеть ) Рад что Вы еще тут. По почте, мог упустить, у меня для Вас тоже ряд предложений есть. Прямо сейчас еще раз пролистал всю почту, подскажите, а какого числа ориентировочно? Может единичку в конце не поставили? Рад был бы с Вами пообщаться. А что касается модераторства - так это же наоборот дополнительная работа, обязательства, просто я же как раз из-за этого ушел, почему-то взбрело в голову, что могу что-то поменять ))) Вообще очень сильно надеялся Вас или (Блин ник забыл, 2 раза КУ желтые штаны на аватарке) увидеть в кандидатах )

Comment: @Sevastopol' нашел ) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/188366/stranger-in-the-q

Comment: КУ желтые штаны? Рассмешили)) Согласен, этот товарищ конечно классный во всех смыслах, и я бы даже сказал - уникальный. Мне он очень симпатичен, и я его уважаю. А я нет, не хочу в модераторы. Тянуть канат, кто кого перетянет .... ну как-то и правда не очень хочется. Но я очень рад за вас, что вы решились. И конечно очень хотелось бы видеть вас в модераторах. Короче, давайте не теряться, на личные темы лучше пообщаемся не здесь, а через почту. chebotarev-pavel@yandex.ru - черкните мне пожалуйста, а я вам в ответ.